# Angular Material button in select

Tags: angular, select, material-design, angular-material, angular5

I try to display button in angular material select and I use this code:

```
<mat-select #placeNameControl="ngModel" placeholder="Place name">
  <mat-option >
    Add new place name
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let addedPlaceName of addedPlaceNames" [value]="addedPlaceName">
    {{addedPlaceName}}
    <button type="buttton" mat-icon-button>
       <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And this works, but when I select one of the options, this display selected element and name of the icon like this:
[image]

This is probably bug in Angular Material but maybe someone know some workaround? I know I can fix this issue with typescript, but this is not the most elegant and clean way.

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Can't figure out what exactly the issue is about. Please add more input and enhance the description.

Comment: This select display name of selected element and name of the icon used inside the button, instead of display only name of selected element.

Comment: Ok, I don't think you can use <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon> for/inside a button tag. But try this: <i class="material-icons">remove</i> instead

Comment: Unfortunately your solution work exactly the same as mine.

Comment: Give it a try as SVG icon... it might not display the SVG markup as a text.

Comment: Boss 8-) That's work great, thanks  ;)

Comment: I would add it as answer, so that you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mat-icon as SVG and give it a try as SVG icon... it might not display the SVG markup as a text.